# Anagram puzzle whose solution is guaranteed to make you laugh

Tags: word, anagram, humor

Rearrange the letters in the name of an African country to produce something a little risque'.

Comment: You might need to be a little more specific. There are [a lot of anagrams of African country names](https://somerandomstuff1.wordpress.com/2014/09/03/anagrams-of-countries/).

Comment: The list you referenced is incomplete. There is enough information in the clue to narrow the number of possibilities.

Comment: OK, that's actually quite neat. +1.

Comment: The title is so clickbaity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> COTE D'IVOIRE,

an anagram of

> EROTIC VIDEO.

The question hints at this as the unique answer by

> saying **risque'** instead of "risqué". This unnecessary use of an apostrophe suggested that we should be looking for words containing apostrophes, and the only country in Africa whose name contains an apostrophe is Cote D'Ivoire.

Comment: A further explanation of the answer: The diacritical mark in risque was, of course, the key. It hinted at an apostrophe in the solution as well as perhaps a French derivation: erotic vide'o is an anagram of cote d'ivoire

Comment: for some reason I read the second word in the answer as "butters". XD

Comment: @TheGreatDuck "The butters is"?

Comment: @randal'thor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0psqsXztEo Thanks for reminding me of this. Now I got it stuck in my head again. XD